# Window's Phone equivalent of Android's Hierarchy Viewer

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Trying to debug some UI and don't want to guess at which file is creating it.
Any one know of a tool for Window's Phone that's similar to Android's Hierarchy Viewer?

Comment: [Xaml Spy](http://xamlspy.com/) is a robust tool. It has a 30 day trial I believe if you want to check it out.